# Mostrar un listado de productos de una tabla mysql cada hora que va cambiando el listado según una condición automáticamente

Tags: php, laravel, angular, ionic

Hola me gustaría si alguien me puede asesorar, quiero mostrar un listado de productos que recojo en una base de datos mysql y quiero mostrar un numero determinado de productos, y que cada hora ese listado se actualiza automáticamente y me muestre los 20 siguientes pero no se si eso se ha de hacer en el controlador de la api que tengo creada en laravel o tendría que hacerlo en la app que estoy haciendo en ionic angular, si alguien puede asesorarme un poco muchas gracias, en el controlador tengo este código para mostrar los productos ahora muestro los 20 primeros y hay me he quedado la verdad no se como hacer que cada hora cambien.

```
class StandoutProductController extends Controller {
  
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

      public function __construct()   {

    }
 
    public function get_all_product_standout(Request $request){
        $result=$this->check_usertoken($request->user_id,$request->api_token);        
        if(!$result)    {
            return response()->json(['status'=>'0', 'msg'=>'Algo ha salido mal.']);
        }
       
        $tmp_list =  Product::join('users','users.user_id','=','product.user_id')
        ->join('standout_product','standout_product.product_id', '=','product.product_id')
        ->join('category','category.category_id','=','product.category_id')
        ->select('product.*','users.firstname','users.lastname','users.image as user_image','users.mobile as user_mobile','users.lat','users.lng','users.address','category.title as category_title')
        ->where('product.status','active')->where('product.standout','1')  
        ->get();
        $Standoutproduct_list=array();
        
        foreach($tmp_list as $val){      
            if($val->address!='')
            $val->address=json_decode($val->address);

            $tmp_filelist=json_decode($val->image_list);
            $result_filelist=[];
            if( $tmp_filelist && count($tmp_filelist)>0){
                foreach($tmp_filelist as $tmp){
                    if ($tmp && $tmp!='')  {
                        $tmp->file_url= $this->site_url.$tmp->file_path;                    
                        $result_filelist[]=$tmp;
                    }                           
                }
            }
            $val->image_list=$result_filelist;

            if( $val->user_image!=''){
                $val->user_image = $this->site_url. "public/uploads/users/".$val->user_image;  
            }else{
                $val->user_image ='';
            }
               
            $Standoutproduct_list[] = $val;
       
        
            
                }
                $Standoutproduct_list = array_slice ($Standoutproduct_list, 0,20);
               /*  
                Standoutproduct::where('product_id', $request->product_id)->update(['active' =>true]); */

               $data=$Standoutproduct_list;   
             
    
        return response()->json(['status'=>'1', 'msg'=>'success','data' => $data]);     
    }

        

}
```

aquí en la app los imprimo así:

```
  get_all_product_standout() {
    var data = {
      'user_id': this.api.userdata.user_id,
      'api_token': this.api.userdata.api_token
    };
    this.dummy = Array(20);

    this.api.get_all_product_standout(data).subscribe((res) => {
      this.dummy = [];
      if (res.status == '1') {
        var tmp_result = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
          

          let start = moment(res.data[i].update_date, "YYYY-MM-DD");
          let end = moment().startOf('day');

          res.data[i].published_dates = moment.duration(end.diff(start)).asDays();
          tmp_result.push(res.data[i]);
        }
        
        tmp_result = orderBy(tmp_result, 'update_date', 'desc');
        this.Standoutproduct_list = tmp_result;

        this.processDeepLinks();

      } else {
        
        this.Standoutproduct_list = [];
      }
    }, error => {

      this.dummy = [];
      this.util.errorToast("Error en el servidor.");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Depende de cómo quieras configurarlo. La API puede devolver los productos a mostrar según la hora en la que se haga la petición o la aplicación puede pedirle a la API qué grupo de productos desea mostrar.

Comment: Hola lobos buena la idea es mostrar 20 productos primero y a la hora siguiente los 20 que le siguen y asi hasta llegar al final de los productos que volvería ha empezar, bueno lo de la petición es cuando se actualiza la pagina vaya.sabes como podria hacerlo en la api que me muestre los 20 siguientes en una hora .

Comment: ¿Eso significa que el usuario tendrá que quedarse esperando 1 hora hasta que aparezcan los otros 20 registros? Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, pero para evitarte trabajo, puedes habilitar un botón que cargue los siguientes registros cuando ya haya terminado con los actuales. Eso lo debes hacer en Angular, Laravel (como api) sólo te dará los productos.

Comment: Hola no tiene que tener un botón ya que son productos destacados y tienen que salir automáticamente.

Comment: ¿Por qué no traerte todos los productos desde el API y crear un slider con `CSS` y `JavaScript` en el front? Si no te gusta esa solución, la otra sería usar setTimeout y utilizar `OFFSET` y `LIMIT` en la query de tu backend.

Comment: Hola jonatan si tengo un slider pero como los productos pueden ir cambiando o agregando mas pues creo que es mejor en la api, dices que con offset y limit se puede hacer eso.

Comment: Aquí hay un [ejemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/c6wrLtpq/1/) usando LIMIT y OFFSET, sólo enfócate en el `setTimeOut` y cómo el OFFSET va aumentando. Todo está en el método llamado `showRowsEach5Seconds()`. Es una idea.

Comment: gracias jonatan